# Has many through Association - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What should be the association for the following criteria.

- A book can have many ratings
- User can add many ratings
- User can add only one rating for a single book

Tables

books - id, title, description

ratings - id, book_id, user_id, value

When a book is selected by the logged in user, i need to get the book details and the rating given by the logged in user.
Something like

```
b = Book.includes(:ratings)
```

Should i use has many through association here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've done something like before. I defined 3 models. `Book, Rating, User`. **Rating** contains the `user_id, book_id` as foreign keys. Only `has_many - belongs` to association is defined. 
`book = Book.find(params[:id]).includes(:ratings)`
`book.ratings.find_by_user_id(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

user.rb

```
has_many :books
has_many :ratings, through: :books
```

book.rb

```
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :users, through: :rating
```

rating.rb

```
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Yes, i have modified the answer.